# Microsoft Word File, file type is not showing as .docx after the upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, file-upload, ms-word

I am writing a file uploader using react and it accepts both `.docx` and `.pdf` files.

```
<Input type="file" onChange={handleImageUpload} accept={'.docx, .pdf'}/>
```

When i upload a `.docx` file, the file type shows as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`. Because of this, i can't create file type validations for uploading for `.docx` files as it rejects all the `.docx` type files. Do i need to change something specifically to overcome this situation?

Comment: The `accept` attribute of HTML elements accepts file extensions like `.docx`, but it also accepts MIME types like `application/vnd...`. Does it work if you use both?

```<input type="file" onChange={handleImageUpload} accept={'.pdf, application/pdf, .docx, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'}/>```

Comment: it accepts both when uploading the file.

Comment: Nice :) Does it solve the original problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the accept in the input tag, I'd go with a hook to check the file type.

something like:

```
<input type="file" onChange={handleFileUpload} accept=".docx, application/pdf" />
```

and then

```
function handleFileUpload(event) {
  const uploadedFile = event.target.files[0];

  // Check if the uploaded file is of the allowed MIME types
  const allowedMimeTypes = ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/pdf'];

  if (uploadedFile && allowedMimeTypes.includes(uploadedFile.type)) {
    // Handle the file upload
  } else {
    // Display an error message or handle invalid file types
  }
}
```

EDIT :

since you're asking WHY the type is "different", here you go:
[MIME TYPES](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)